# What is the year, make, and model of this car?

Tags: vehicle-identification

[image: what year was this pic taken]

I'm trying to figure out what year I took this picture. This was a brand new car at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google search of the names on the door brought up this page -

http://www.comicozzie.com/gallery2/v/1992/EC/92IIRA-42.jpg.html

Which says that it is a 1992 Mercury Capri XR2

When I did a google search for a Mercury Capri XR2 it found cars that looked the same.  Since I am not from the USA, I can only presume that it is correct, since I have never seen one before.

Comment: OP needs to recognize the power of google : plus one.

Comment: That is definitely the car. Thank You. Did you search the drivers names or the sponsors names?

Comment: @KelleyStieh you asked about the car, not the drivers. You can do a google search for those now.

Comment: @KelleyStieh I searched for Menard and Kurshinsky.  Another page showed that they were John and Jon, so added that to the search.

Comment: @HandyHowie, Menards is the name of a home improvement chain in the American Midwest.

Comment: @GdD The 110th-richest person in the world, apparently, yet never heard of him.  Looks like his family are into racing.

Comment: @GdD Also looks like Jon Kurshinsky works at Menards.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why the interest @HandyHowie?

Comment: @GdD Absolutely none really.  Just your comment about the home improvement chain made me look him up.

Comment: @SolarMike I was curious how it was found so quickly and accurately. I will have remember for next time I'm searching.